# Проблема при загрузке данных из SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Я храню ArrayList со строковыми значениями в Sharedpreferences, сохраняю таким путем:

`SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LW",MODE_PRIVATE);`

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    gson = new Gson();
    String jsonCars = gson.toJson(subject);
    editor.putString("myJson", jsonCars);
    Log.d("TAG","jsonCars = " + jsonCars);
    editor.commit();`
```

В логах отображение сохранения списка по типу: `D/TAG: jsonCars = {"SubFullForm":"Пионерский 25","SubName":"Социум","TextTimenaho":"0","TextViews":"0000001002","TextViewssotr":"0000001002"}`

Но загрузить обратно в список не могу, приложение вылетает, пытаюсь загрузить вот так:

```
public ArrayList<Subject> Loads() {
SubjectList= new ArrayList<Subject>();
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("LW", MODE_PRIVATE);
gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("myJson", "");
if (json.isEmpty()) {
    SubjectList= new ArrayList<Subject>();
} else {
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Subject>>() {
    }.getType();
   SubjectList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
return  SubjectList ;}
```

AndroidMonitor  указывает на эту строчку ошибки `SubjectList = gson.fromJson(json, type);`

Как загрузить нормально список раннее сохраненный?

Comment: Вы же сохраняете один объект `(subject)`, а восстановить хотите из него целый список.